# Insert new line when updating field in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using

```
update_sub_field( array('subscribers_lists',$field_row,'subscribers'), $current_subscribers );
```

to update certain custom fields.

Everything works as expected except when `$current_subscribers` has `'\n'`or `<br>` - it won't do a new line as I would expect.

How would I force a new line when adding text to a field using ACF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talked with some developers and they said you cannot do this with a normal text field or textarea. You have to use WYSIWYG field instead.

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty workaround if really need to save new lines in ACF textarea:

```
$post_id = 123;
$data = "lorem \n ipsum";
$field_name = 'my_field';
$data_modified = str_replace("\n", '__N__', $data);

// writing data
update_field($field_name, $data_modified, $post_id);

// reading data
$data_modified = get_field($field_name, $post_id);
$data = str_replace('__N__', "\n", $data_modified);
```